# Subset related bit manipulation

Tags: c++, bit-manipulation

I want to know what this bit manipulation means:

```
for (int m = 1; m < (1 << n); ++m) {
    for (int s = m; s; s = (s - 1) & m) {
        // ....
    }
}
```

The first for-loop is to enumerate all subsets of n elements, but what the *second for-loop* means?

Comment: Do it by hand a few times for a few inputs. Do you notice anything? If you're diving into bit manipulation you might also want to check out https://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html.

Comment: Wow thanks for the link, never know there is such an extensive collection for bit manipulation tricks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `s` is of the form `...10000` then `s-1` is `...01111`. We then `&` with `m`, which leaves only those `1` in the lower portion that were also present in `m`. (The upper bits of `s` stay untouched and remain identical to those in `m`).

Effectively, we clear the least set bit in `s` and replace all lower bits with those in `m`. It can be seen that this amounts to "counting downwards within the set bits of `m`". That is, if `m` has `k` set bits, count down from `(1<<k)-1` and, for each of those 2<sup>k</sup> numbers, distribute its `k` bits into the `k` positions that `m` had set bits in.

Or, if we interpret `m` as a bitset, it **enumerates all subsets of `m`** (including `m` but skipping the empty subset).